# SQL create 2 tables with constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, ddl, create-table

Starting with first table: create the two tables with constraints

```
CREATE TABLE department
(
    depid varchar2(3) CONSTRAINT PKdepid PRIMARY KEY,
    dname varchar2(10) NOT NULL
);
```

First table is created.

Starting second table:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    eid number CONSTRAINT PKEID PRIMARY KEY, 
    ename varchar2(10), 
    depid varchar2(3) 
        CONSTRAINT FKDEPID 
             FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE dep(depid),
    designation varchar2(10),
    salary number CHECK (salary > 10000),
    doj date
);

CREATE TABLE employee
(
    eid number CONSTRAINT PKEID PRIMARY KEY, 
    ename varchar2(10), 
    depid varchar2(3) 
        CONSTRAINT FKDEPID 
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE dep(depid),
    designation varchar2(10),
    salary number CHECK (salary > 10000),
    doj date
)
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here

And in second condition applied

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    eid number CONSTRAINT PKEID PRIMARY KEY, 
    ename varchar2(10), 
    depid varchar2(3) 
         CONSTRAIN FKDEPID 
             FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE dep(depid),
    designation varchar2(10),
    salary number CHECK (salary > 10000),
    doj date
);

CREATE TABLE employee
(
    eid number CONSTRAINT PKEID PRIMARY KEY, 
    ename varchar2(10), 
    depid varchar2(3) 
         CONSTRAIN FKDEPID 
             FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE dep(depid),
    designation varchar2(10),
    salary number CHECK (salary > 10000),
    doj date
)
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I just wanted to create table

Comment: I removed the TAG spam; please re-tag your question with the correct DBMS - which is probably none of the ones you tagged.

Comment: Please specify which RDBMS you're using. SQL Server, MySQL and postgres use differing syntaxes. Judging by the error messages it would appear you're using Oracle? Please explain the problem you're trying to solve - detail the outcome you need.

Comment: Lose the `CONSTRAINT` keyword. That is used when you create a table constraint, not when you are creating it directly on the column. Spend some time here [Create table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) for Postgres.

Comment: Typos: twice you have `CONSTRAIN` - it **must be** `CONSTRAINT`  (with `T` at the end). Also: you have `FOREIGN KEY ... REFERENCE .....` - but it **must be** `REFERENCES` with a `S` at the end .... pro tip: **READ THE DOCS!!** They clearly spell out exactly how your syntax needs to be - that's what they're there for!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't specify `foreign key` in an inline foreign key definition, just `references` (not `reference` as you currently have). Also, note your statement references the table `dep` while your other table is in fact called `department`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (
  eid NUMBER CONSTRAINT pkeid PRIMARY KEY, 
  ename VARCHAR2(10), 
  depid VARCHAR2(3) CONSTRAINT fkdepid REFERENCES department(depid), -- Here!
  designation VARCHAR2(10),
  salary NUMBER CHECK(salary>10000),
  doj DATE);
```

Comment: While we are on spelling mistakes it should be `TABLE` not `TAEBL`. Also you don't need to use the `CONSTRAINT` keyword. Only needed if you want to explicitly name the constraint, otherwise Postgres will create a name.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver good catch on the typo, thanks. Edited and fixed. Not sure why you're referencing Postgres though. The question is about Oracle

Comment: Still not fixed.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver :facepalm: I just can't seem to type straight today... thanks again